# How to replace environment variable inside yml file when running docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, prometheus

I'd like to pass env variables to an yml file which will be used as a config file for a certain container.

Here's my file tree.

```
alertmanager
  - .env
  - alertmanager.yml
prometheus
  - prometheus.yml
  - rules.yml
docker-compose.yml
```

Here's a code what's inside a docker-compose file.

```
  alertmanager:
    image: prom/alertmanager
    container_name: alertmanager
    ports:
      - 9093:9093
    volumes:
      - ./alertmanager/:/etc/alertmanager/
    restart: always
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml'
      - '--storage.path=/alertmanager'
    env_file:
      - ./alertmanager/.env
```

and alaertmanager.yml looks like below.

```
route:
  receiver: "slack"

receivers:
  - name: "slack"
    slack_configs:
      - send_resolved: true
        username: ${USERNAME}
        channel: ${CHANNEL}
        api_url: ${SLACK_URL}
```

A problem is alertmanager.yml recognize `${SLACK_URL}` as a string.
I guess it's because alertmanage.yml is a static file and there is no engine to replace `${SLACK_URL}` to something like `http://slack_url.com`.

I saw some answers to solve this problem.
First option is create a python script which can replace `${}` to env variable. However, as far as I know, I need to contain python inside docker image.
Another option is using `envsubst`. But, again, I need to enable `envsubst` command in docker image. In both ways, I need to customize a docker image which I think is bothersome.

Is there any solution to solve this problem?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Docker Compose never makes any modifications to files, whether stored in images or bind-mounted from the host.  You'll have to either update the content on the host to have the right specific values or modify the container startup, probably with a custom derived image.

Answer (score 1):

### Test this on your yml file. It is working on my ruby on rails development.

```
slack_url: <%= ENV['SLACK_URL'] %>
```

---

compose.yml

```
environment:
  SLACK_URL: some_url
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Also using ${SLACK_HOOK_URL} didn't work. Maybe is because of this https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/2357#issuecomment-274267593. In summary, prometheus did not support environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to run `envsubst` without changing the docker file is to modify the entrypoint of the container via the compose file. For that you need to check the original entrypoint of the image you are using.

```
    entrypoint: "envsubst < \"source.txt\" | sponge \"source.txt\" && <entrypoint of image>"
```

This assumes that `envsubst` and `sponge` are installed in the image. If not you can either write a script that does the same work, mount it and run via the same technique, or you add instructions to install the commands. This can be done in a script as well.